# Ag-grid custom cellEditor

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

Is it possible automatically add commas when editing a number cell inside angular Ag-grid grid?

https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/cell-editors/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your column definition you can add a [`valueFormatter`](https://www.ag-grid.com/vue-data-grid/value-formatters/):

```js
  columnDefs: [
    { field: 'type' },
    {
      field: 'value',
      editable: true,
      cellEditorSelector: cellEditorSelector,
      valueFormatter: (params) =>
        typeof params.value === 'number'
          ? new Intl.NumberFormat().format(params.value)
          : params.value,
    },
  ],
```

Or if your column/field only contains numbers, you can simplify value formatter to:

`valueFormatter: (params) => new Intl.NumberFormat().format(params.value)`

And here are docs on the [`NumberFormat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat)